# C# WCF Service and Java Client

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wcf

Please help with Java Client for C# WCF Service, which is throwing:

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Undefined port type: {http://tempuri.org/}WCFService
      at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
      at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Unknown Source)
      at Client.main(Client.java:20)

```

Here's the Java Code Snippet:

```
import java.net.URL;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

public class Client {

    @WebService(name = "WCFService", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
    public interface IWCFService {
        @WebMethod
        String Echo(String input);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        QName port = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "WCFService");
        URL location = new URL("http://localhost:8000/WCFService?wsdl");
        Service serv = Service.create(location, port);
        IWCFService p = serv.getPort(IWCFService.class);
        System.out.println(p.Echo("Hello World!"));
    }
}
```

Here's the WCF Code Snippet:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace WCFWSDL
{
    public class Program
    {
        [ServiceContract]
        public interface IWCFService
        {
            [OperationContract]
            string Echo(string input);
        }

        public class WCFService : IWCFService
        {
            public string Echo(string input) { return "Your input: " + input; }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000/WCFService";
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFService), new Uri(baseAddress));
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWCFService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("http://localhost:8000/WCFService?wsdl");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close");
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks